# Error trying to call method from server on GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to call a method  from my server side whose signature is

`public Integer method()`

but when I redid all the steps used on the StockWatcher tutorial to call it, I'm getting a 404 error which says this is the URL

`<p>RequestURI=/com.medtronic.empattendance.EmployeeAttendance/empQueries</p>`

I'm not sure what the correct URL should be, but this is the incorrect URL.

my web.xml says this on servlets

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>empQueryServerImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.medtronic.empattendance.server.EmpQueryServerImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>empQueryServerImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/empattendance/empQueries</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I actually solved this, I needed to place the whole package name on <url-pattern>.

Comment: If you have it solved you should post the solution as answered and then accept your own answer. That way others won't waste their time trying to figure it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative: Use the `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` [(javadoc)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteServiceRelativePath.html) annotation on your RPC class (The interface extending RemoteService, not the Async one).

Assuming your GWT app is `/empattendance`:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("empQueries")
public interface EmpQueryServer extends RemoteService {
    // your methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it:

I had <`url-pattern>/empattendance/empQueries</url-pattern>` which was based off the tutorial, but digging deeper I found out I needed to use the full package name.

`<url-pattern>/com.myCompany.empattendance.EmployeeAttendance/empQueries</url-pattern>`